# Inserting columns but have problem with the merged cells

Tags: python, excel, insert, openpyxl

I'm in a struggle, i want to insert some columns to 'M' column.

[image]

As you can see there are merged cells and when I insert eg.: 3 columns i get the following output:

[image]

So the 'N' and 'O' columns remained as a merged cell and at the 'X' column should be merged.
My output should look like this:

[image]

Is there any possible way to get the last example's output?

This is my code:

```
wb = load_workbook('new_test.xlsx')
 
ws = wb.active
 
ws.insert_cols(13,3)

wb.save('new_test.xlsx')
```

Comment: You'll have to update the merged cells yourself manually.

Comment: I have thousands of these so that is not option, i think i will save the coordinates of the merged cells and unmerge them after i insert the new columns.

Comment: MergedCell ranges are extremely flexible and the work is the same whether you or openpyxl does it.